# Triangular images in a shape of a diamond

Tags: html, css, position, absolute, css-shapes

I'm pretty new at this, and I am having some issues with positioning some images the way I want it.
This is what I want:

[image]

```css
a:link: 
a:visited: 
a:hover

.thumbnail {
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Element width position calculated with:
(((1-((229/2)*x+(20*y))/1080)/2)+((229/2+20)/1080)*z)*100

x = number of triangles in row
y = number of spaces between triangles
z = triangle number from starting postion left -1

Vertical:
(((1-(844/1080))/2)+((196+20)/1080)*z)*100
*/

body {
    background: url(Resources/forside_baggrund.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.Diamond {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.Diamond img {
    width: 229px;
    height: 196px;
    position:absolute;
}

.room {
    width: 114.5px;
    height: 131px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:transparent;
    left: 50%;
    top: 36%;
}

.info {
    width: 114.5px;
    height: 131px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:transparent;
    left: 37.3%;
    top: 56%;
}

.language {
    width: 114.5px;
    height: 131px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:transparent;
    left: 50%;
    top: 51%;
}

.kursus {
    width: 114.5px;
    height: 131px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:transparent;
    left: 62.2%;
    top: 56%;
}

/* Top Row */
.Diamond>:first-child {
    left: 32.2453703704%;
    top: 10.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(2) {
    left: 44.6990740741%;
    top: 10.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(3) {
    left: 57.1527777778%;
    top: 10.9259259259%;
}

/* Second Row */
.Diamond>:nth-child(4) {
    left: 19.7916666667%;
    top: 30.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(5) {
    left: 32.2453703704%;
    top: 30.9259259259%;
} 

.Diamond>:nth-child(6) {
    left: 44.6990740741%;
    top: 30.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(7) {
    left: 57.1527777778%;
    top: 30.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(8) {
    left: 69.6064814815%;
    top: 30.9259259259%;
}

/* Third Row */
.Diamond>:nth-child(9) {
    left: 7.33796296296%;
    top: 50.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(10) { 
    left: 19.7916666667%;
    top: 50.9259259259%;
} 

.Diamond>:nth-child(11) {
    left: 32.2453703704%;
    top: 50.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(12) {
    left: 44.6990740741%;
    top: 50.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(13) {
    left: 57.1527777778%;
    top: 50.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(14) {
    left: 69.6064814815%;
    top: 50.9259259259%;
}
.Diamond>:nth-child(15) {
    left: 82.0601851852%;
    top: 50.9259259259%;
}

/* Fourth Row */
.Diamond>:nth-child(16) {
    left: 7.33796296296%;
    top: 70.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(17) { 
    left: 19.7916666667%;
    top: 70.9259259259%;
} 

.Diamond>:nth-child(18) {
    left: 32.2453703704%;
    top: 70.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(19) {
    left: 44.6990740741%;
    top: 70.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(20) {
    left: 57.1527777778%;
    top: 70.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(21) {
    left: 69.6064814815%;
    top: 70.9259259259%;
}

.Diamond>:nth-child(22) {
    left: 82.0601851852%;
    top: 70.9259259259%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>www.klejstruplund.dk/Forside</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="Diamond">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Koekken.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Kongelys.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Hoene.png">  
    <img src="Resources/Triangles/Gaardvindue.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Sorttomat.png">
 <img src="Resources/Buttons/Vearelser.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/View.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Besser_Rev.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Fidus.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Demon.png">
 <img src="Resources/Buttons/Kursus.png">
 <img src="Resources/Buttons/Union_Jack.png">
 <img src="Resources/Buttons/Om_stedet.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Drivhus.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Indenfor.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Mereindenfor.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Huset.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/fidusiovn.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Apples.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Cabbage.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Pond.png">
 <img src="Resources/Triangles/Filtsommerfugl.png">
 <a href="#"><div class="room" alt="Leje af Vaerelse"></div></a>
 <a href="#"><div class="info" alt="Information om stedet"></div></a>
 <a href="#"><div class="language" alt="Change Language to English"></div></a>
 <a href="#"><div class="kursus" alt="Information om kurser"></div></a>
  </div>      
</body> 
</html>
```

I've tried to follow different solutions, but all have failed so far, the latest resulted in all the images being placed vertically. 
I know I could probably make it easier by creating the pattern as an image, but as this is a learning process for me, I want to do it using the tools of CSS.

After a bit of searching and experimentation, I decided on absolutely positioned images, in a Relatively positioned div:

etc. in all 22 Equilateral triangles.

This resulted in the aforementioned tower of triangles and I decided to get some help before I list my patience. What am I missing?

**Update**
I added the full code for html and css, though since the problem is now solved, it seems slightly superfluous, all I can say is that I now get the result that I want.

The problem as I was informed, was that I had gotten the selectors backward; thinking .Diamond:nth-child(2) meant the second child of container div class Diamond would be selected. I've now add a ">" between .Diamond and :nth-child(x)/:first-child.
Silly mistake.

Comment: You need to post a working example with your markup.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem, you need to post more code. However, I do can tell you that setting width: 229px for every child number is redundant. and also height 196px

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `.Diamond` is your *container*.

So you want `.Diamond>:first-child` to get the first child of `.Diamond` - otherwise, you'll be getting the `.Diamond` that *is* the first child of *its* container.

So basically, none of your styles are being applied.

Quick tip:

```
.Diamond>div {
    width:229px;
    height:196px;
}
```

No sense in duplicating that for *all* of your triangles.

Comment: Yes, that pretty much solved it, as you said, I got the selector backward.

Comment: I had actually used http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp as reference, but despite using a few selectors in combination, I had overlooked ">". the Diamond class div is indeed the container for the images. Thank you very much.